# Why mysql sum not working in mysql view table?

Tags: mysql, view, sum

I am using the following query to get total score from mysql view table

```
Select regd, date, subject, (t_scored+w_scored+f_scored+cce_scored) as Total
from
exam_view
where regd='3'
group by subject
```

In the total column I only get `NULL` where there are field values for each scored field. Please can anyone help me?

Comment: Are those fields numeric?

Comment: @ Hanky 웃 Panky, Yes, they are numeric.

Comment: Can we see all the data of that specific row where the id is 3?

Comment: In fact, instead of id, regd must be there.

Comment: How many rows does this query return? You might want to `SUM()` them

Comment: It can be so many rows.

Comment: Please try to be more descriptive when giving feedback, 'does not work' and 'so many rows' do not help much. Anyway I've updated my answer which I think should solve your problem, as essentially you wanted to sum the sum of the sums in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an inline query to get separate sums, and the outer query to add up the sums

```
SELECT regd, date, subject, SUM(t_scored+w_scored+f_scored+cce_scored) AS total
FROM
(
SELECT regd, date, subject, SUM(t_scored) as t_scored, SUM(w_scored) as w_scored, SUM(f_scored) AS f_scored, SUM(cce_scored) AS cce_scored
FROM
exam_view
WHERE regd='3'
) AS temp
GROUP BY subject
```

Comment: Every derived table must have its own alias. This is the error message

Comment: Updated answer (AS temp) at the end of subquery